flutter' is not an internal or external command
I have installed the Flutter SDK but when I run
flutter doctor

It says I haven't. How do you fix this
I ran
flutter doctor

and was expecting there to be what I had which was recommended and what I didn't have which was recommended. Instead I got this:
'flutter' is not an internal or external command.


Please search this site for that error message. This question has been asked and answered here literally dozens of times before. Before asking a new question here, ALWAYS do a thorough search. It's clear that you made no effort to solve this yourself before posting, and we expect you to do so. This should be the last resort in solving a problem, not the first.

This question is similar to: 'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. There are also 115 other results from searching with the exact title you used in your post.

You need to add path your bin directory to system environments
Enter System Env
Open Env Variables
Click Edit
Click New and add your flutter/bin path then apply
After this steps try to runflutter doctor

On Mac I have encountered this issue before. If you are on Windows I don't know the exact solution but the general idea is the same.
On Mac go to your .zshrc or .bash file. Add this line:
export PATH="$PATH:path_to_flutter/flutter/bin"

Restart your terminal. Then run Flutter Doctor and it should work.
This is the manual way to do this as, recently, exporting to path doesn't always work while following installation instructions.
